# How configure SSL for an IIS Express site that uses multiple hostnames?

Tags: ssl, https, iis-express, netsh, makecert

My web application project encompasses multiple web sites served under the umbrella of a single IIS Express site.  I succeeded in following Scott Hanselman's [excellent blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx), and IIS Express successfully serves both http://foo.local and http://bar.local from the same web application root directory.

However, I need both sites to support SSL.  Following Hanselman's advice, I can create an SSL certificate and "attach" it to a single IP-port combination.

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=foo.local" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 appid='{214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74b}' certhash=284475d4a4eb5c4d3ab7da4fdefa928186482376
```

That succeeds, but I am unable to repeat the process for the second site.  Evidently only one SSL certificate can be applied to a single IP-port combination.

How can I make an SSL certificate that covers both https://foo.local and https://bar.local, or otherwise "attach" one for each site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jww's answer led me in the right direction.  Beyond Hanselman's [instructions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx), here's what I had to do.

First of all, I enabled SNI on my site bindings in IIS Express' applicationhosts.config.  This just meant appending the `sslFlags` attribute:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:foo.local" sslFlags="1" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:bar.local" sslFlags="1" />
```

(credit: [Configure SNI On IIS8?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omnia/archive/2012/11/11/how-to-use-sni.aspx))

Then instead of using `makecert`, I created a self-signed certificate using PowerShell's `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName foo.local, bar.local -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

(credit: [How to create a Self-Signed SAN Certificate in Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/07/20/how-to-create-a-self-signed-san-certificate-in-windows-8.aspx))

Beside that, I followed Hanselman's instructions to use `netsh http add sslcert...` to "register" the certificate for the IP-port, and to use the MMC "Certificates" snap-in to make it trusted.

Answer (score 2):

> Evidently only one SSL certificate can be applied to a single IP-port combination...

You need IIS 8 or above to use multiple certificates. IIS 8 support Server Name Indication (SNI). See [Server Name Indication (SNI) with IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx).

---

> How can I make an SSL certificate that covers both `https://foo.local` and `https://bar.local` ...

Create one certificate. In the certificate, place both names in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN). Place a friendly name in the CN.

The CN should be a friendly name because:

1. The IETF deprecated placing a DNS name in the CN
2. The CA/Browser Forums deprecated placing a DNS name in the CN
3. CN's are often displayed to users, so they should be friendly

---

> ... or otherwise "attach" one for each site?

Upgrade to IIS 8 or Server 2012.

---

> Following Hanselman's advice... `makecert -r -pe -n "CN=foo.local"`

His advice is wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, jww.  The latest IIS Express leverages IIS 8's SNI support, so you led me in the right direction.